# Updating array select values onchange in uniform

Tags: javascript, jquery, uniform

Using uniform for a form I'm working on, and i'm adding fields dynamically by cloning the following:

```
<label for="USState">US State:</label>
<select name="USState[]" class="">
    <option value="" selected="selected">Select State</option>
```

The fields are all working fine, apart from when I apply uniform...

```
$(function () {

    $uniformed = $(".styleThese").find("input, textarea, select, button, a.uniformTest").not(".skipThese");
    $uniformed.uniform({selectAutoWidth: false});

    $("select").change(function() {
    $.uniform.update();
    });
});
```

I've tried adding in a change function to update all fields, but whilst the first dropdown changes, the clones don't, although the values are still passed through fine.

Edit:

Added to a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nwgnygsf/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are adding elements to the page dynamically, most likely the event isn't getting triggered because there is no handler attached to it.
Try changing this:

```
$("select").change(function() {
    $.uniform.update();
});
```

To this:

```
$(document).on("change", "select", function() {
    $uniformed = $(".styleThese").find("input, textarea, select, button, a.uniformTest").not(".skipThese");
    $uniformed.uniform({selectAutoWidth: false});
    $.uniform.update();
});
```

**EDIT**

Based on the comments, [I have updated your JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nwgnygsf/1/) with some changes that may help you further.

Comment: No dice unfortunately. Should I be adding something to the part where the fields are created? `$("#add").click(function() {
          $('#USStateTaxBox').clone(true).insertBefore('#buttonholder');
          return false;
});`

Comment: @BN83 I made an update to my answer. Again, I think what's happening is that when you make calls like `$("select")` and `.find("")` it performs the actions RIGHT THEN. So any items added after the fact are not going to have events on them or be apart of the previous list of queried items.

Comment: have just tried that, but still it didn't work. So I tried adding the `$.uniform.update()` function to a button `$("#update").click(function() { $.uniform.update(); });` and that didn't update it either...

Comment: @BN83 What browser are you using?

Comment: Chrome on Mac, but have tested in Firefox and Safari, same issue. It styles it, but just doesn't show the selected item.

Comment: @BN83 The fiddle you created seems to be working perfectly as is in Chrome v43 on Win7 PC. However, in IE v11 it's not working. I am testing it out now.

Comment: Just to confirm, is it the second/third/fourth dropdown that is working for you? Or the first one? The first one is working fine for me, it's when I add the others, they don't show the selected values.

Comment: @BN83 All of them are being styled. The first one and all of the clones added by clicking the Add button. I even commented out the update line and the new additions are still being styled properly. Again this is in Chrome 43 on Win7 PC

Comment: Styling isn't the issue, what happens when you try to select one of the options on any of the dynamically added ones?

Comment: @BN83 Well, nothing does. There is no event/action associated with a change on the dropdowns.

Comment: @BN83 I have updated my answer. Please check out the link I added to JSFiddle to see if the changes I made help you at all...

Comment: That's done the trick cheers buddy. Have marked your answer as correct.